Unity AudioClip.PCMReaderCallback is not being called when audioBuffer is written
I'm having some trouble with using PCMReaderCallback. The callback is never called when the audioBuffer is filled. It should be called automatically by Unity. Here is a sample of my code:
private MemoryStream audioBuffer;
async void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log("Start");
            audioBuffer = new MemoryStream();
            // Initialize the audio clip and buffer
            audioClip = AudioClip.Create("ElevenLabsTTS", 44100, 1, 44100, true, PcmReader);
 
            await ConnectToWebSocket();  //Some logic is implemented here to send the message to web socket and receive a byte[] from it
            audioSource.clip = audioClip;
            audioSource.Play();
            Debug.Log("Playing audio clip");
        }
 
private void PcmReader(float[] data)
        {
            if (null == audioBuffer || audioBuffer.Length == 0) return;
 
            // Create a binary reader for the memory buffer
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(audioBuffer))
            {
                Debug.Log("audioBuffer is read");
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (audioBuffer.Position < audioBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        // Read a 16-bit sample from the memory buffer
                        short sample = reader.ReadInt16();
                        // Convert the sample to a float in the range -1 to 1 and store it in the data array
                        data[i] = sample / 32768f;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If there is no more data in the memory buffer, fill the rest of the data array with zeros
                        data[i] = 0f;
                    }
                }
            }          
 
            if (audioBuffer.Position >= audioBuffer.Length) audioBuffer.SetLength(0);
        }

When the message is received from the socket, which is the audio of "Hello", this audioBuffer is filled.
websocket.OnMessage += (bytes) =>
            {
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                // Debug.Log("OnMessage : "+message);
                var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<MessageData>(message);
                if (data.audio != null)
                {
                    byte[] audioData = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data.audio);
                    audioBuffer.Write(audioData);
                    Debug.Log("Added audio data");
                }
            };

At this point, PcmReader() should be called, but is not. What am I missing? Appreciate if anyone could help me here.
As per my understanding, PcmReader() should be called whenever audioBuffer is filled internally by Unity. This is not happening. The AudioSource is correctly configured and is not paused or stopped at any point. The audioClip Play() is called but no audio is observed.

Do you think the method was not called simply because you didn't hear any sound? Did you see "audioBuffer is read" or any errors in the console?

No, I don't get that log "audioBuffer is read".

Maybe audioBuffer is empty, try to move the log to the start of the method.

Yes, PcmReader() is called multiple times immediately after the audioclip is created. In those instance, audioBuffer is empty. But when I press a button, which causes a websocket response and I write that response to the audioBuffer [audioBuffer.Write(audioData);], then also PcmReader() should be called internally but it is not.

Why should it be called internally? Ask yourself how Unity knows the buffer is related to the clip? You need to explicitly play the audio to inform Unity to request the audio data.

May be something lacking in my understanding. Here is the whole source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16zIp_k2rV9k6-gatemnekFNHr8jmcdEO/view?usp=sharing . I expect that when Speak() is called, then I should hear something but not. Where do you suggest that I play the audio?

You can play the audio after you've filled the audioBuffer.

I have slightly modified the code (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YPePaPqnbH7b3yfXKD4FCXL8_Zbr5uln/view?usp=sharing) and now calling the audioSource Play() after writing to the audioBuffer. Still I don't hear anything. I now see that PcmReader() is called when I call Play() but don't hear any sound or receive any error

Try to set audioBuffer.Position = 0L after writing to it.

That did cause some audio! But it was all garbage and also raised this exception: EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

That could be a problem with the data.

Let me confirm on that but thanks a lot for your help!
